# Finding files only inside a directory based on file extensions and not in sub-directories inside the directory

Tags: python, directory-structure, os.walk

I need to iterate through different folders and check if certain files are present inside directory based on their file extensions.

However during iteration it is also checking on the subfolders present inside the main folder and checking if files are present inside the sub-folder. How to avoid this search?

For e.g., the main path is D:\Tools\Results. Inside Results, I have two folders: Test_Results_Day1 and Test_Results_Day2. I want to check for files ending with file extensions only in these two folders. Suppose if there are folders with any name inside Test_Results_Day1 and Test_Results_Day2, it should not enter into those folders and perform the check

Tried to compare with subdir, but able to get for only for the first directory The results for Test_Results_Day2 folder are not displayed

Request to help me out on this...

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(sw_files_path):
    matching_files = [file for file in files if file.endswith(file_format)]
    if subdir.lower().endswith(now+"\Test_Results_Day1"):
        if len(matching_files) > 0:
            print(f"\nFiles are present in '{subdir}'")
            for file_name in matching_files:
                print(f"{file_name} - Latest file available")
            else:
                print(f"{file_name} - Latest file not available")
    if subdir.__contains__(now+"\Test_Results_Day2"):
        if len(matching_files) > 0:
            print(f"\nFiles are present in '{subdir}'")
            for file_name in matching_files:
                print(f"{file_name} - Latest file available")
            else:
                print(f"{file_name} - Latest file not available")
```

Comment: To prevent `os.walk` from searching in deeper subdirectories you can edit the list in `dirs`, e. g. with `del dirs[:]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
os.listdir(sw_files_path)
```

which return a list of the contents of sw_files_path (files and subfolders) without the content of subfoldes. os.walk() is used for searching whole file trees.

Comment: This is a correct answer, but it should probably be updated to demonstrate exactly how to solve the OP's specific problem.